# Remove quotes from ns mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Code:

```
NSString *advName = result[i][@"AdvertiserName"];

NSString *trimmedString = [advName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"sas"]; 

NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString); 

[self.mutableNames addObject:trimmedString]; 
    NSString *advName = result[i][@"AdvertiserName"];

 NSString *trimmedString = [advName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"sas"];

 NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString); 

[self.mutableNames addObject:trimmedString];

 NSLog(@"%@", self.mutableNames);
```

self.mutableNames : The output is:

```
(
adcamie,
adcamie,
Advertiser,
Advertiser,
Advertiser,
Advertiser,
Advertiser,
aerocwl,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
Alex,
"Amanda tan",
APVISA1,
APVISA1,
chin,
"CS Yong",
"Demo Advertiser",
"dinobsya@gmail.com",
"EdmondGooY.M.",
Flannery,
"frankwong@moredesign.asia",
GANDHI,
innovation,
iristeoh,
Ivalent,
Iyashino,
jerryyong,
laich0325,
"mahyuenlung@hotmail.com",
mars,
"maxmax889@hotmail.com",
"mcom hk 2",
"mcom hk cpa",
"Mcom International HK",
"MCOM Thai",
"MCOM Thai",
MCOMMessaging,
"meifen.low@gmail.com",
Minnie,
Mobvista,
"mw_manwai",
"phyllis ng",
"Property Hunter",
"Qiji Wuxian",
"seco builtech design",
StreamerTech,
TestingAdva,
top1,
"tsuka90@gmail.com",
"yching.property@gmail.com",
youmi
)
```

Comment: This looks like an NSArray of strings logged in the console using NSLog. No need to worry, you might notice, that the double quotes are only in those strings with multiple words. This is just to show their grouping.

Comment: If your problem is something else, I would suggest you explain it in more that just a console output.

Comment: What code? Also, please explain the problem in sufficient detail. What do you mean by wanting to remove the quotes? Please provide an expected output as well.

Comment: NSString *advName = result[i][@"AdvertiserName"];

                     NSString *trimmedString = [advName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"sas"];
                     NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString);
                     [self.mutableNames addObject:trimmedString];

Comment: thanks for the replay, my problem is, I'm getting the quote for few strings. So, I want to remove those quotes

Comment: I want every string in an array without quotes like string - Alex

Comment: Please edit your question with the code, instead of adding it as a comment.

Comment: As I have said earlier, this will happen in a console output. They will not include quotes when used somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [objectiveC NSMutableArray add NSMutableDictionary issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411756/objectivec-nsmutablearray-add-nsmutabledictionary-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to clean up the output, you can write a simple loop:

```
for (NSString *name in self.mutableNames)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", name);
}
```

Comment: Cleaning is working but I want NSArray with those cleaned strings, possible?

Comment: The problem is that there is NO problem. If you log an NSArray of strings to the console, they will be printed like that. It's just how console logs get printed. The point is, WHY do you want to remove quotes while printing to the console?

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing table view search. I want to pass this NSArray to filter method, that method want NSArray not NSMutableArray

Comment: NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, so you can pass the same as well.